# Create a new image using Magick++

Tags: c++, c, image, imagemagick, magick++

I have a vector something of this sort

```
typedef struct
{
  int r,g,b;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
rgbs;

vector<rgbs> rgbt;

rgbs rgb;
for(int row=0;row<100; row++)
{
  for(int col=0;col<100; col++)
  {
     rgb.r=col+row;
     rgb.g=col+row;
     rgb.b=col+row;
     rgbt.push_back(rgb);
  }
}
```

What will be an efficient way to form a new image out of this vector using magick++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zaffy was right::

32 bit integer cannot be used in this case as the sizeof pixelpacket pointer to a red, blue or green pixel is 16 bit.

So, we need to use 16 bit unsigned integer from the stdint library

```
#include<stdint.h>
typedef uint16_t WORD;
```

Now in the structure rgbs we initialise WORD r,g,b instead.

The way to initialise Blob is : Blob blob(address of the pixel data, size of data)
So, the code will be something like this:

```
Blob blob(&rgbt[0],(rgbt.size()*sizeof(rgbt[0]));
Image image;
image.size("100x100");
image.magick("RGB");
image.read(blob);
```

Answer (score 1):

I customized an example from [Magick++ API](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) documentation for you.

```
Blob blob( &rgbt[0], rgbt.size() / sizeof(rgbt[0]) );
Image image;
image.size( "100x100") 
image.magick( "RGB" ); 
image.read( blob);
```

But I am not sure if you should use one byte `unsigned char` instead of 4 bytes `int`. Give it a try and you'll see.

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorCorruptImage'
  what():  Magick: unexpected end-of-file `': No such file or directory @ error/rgb.c/ReadRGBImage/229
Aborted (core dumped)